Symbolic links and moving directories
Situation: I have a folder (MM) on my C Drive, move it to a Folder on my E Drive (E:\Data) and create a symbolic link (mklink /j C:\MM E:\Data\MM). For some reason, I need to move the MM folder to a subfolder on the E Drive (E:\Data\Previous), will the link update or do I have to create a new link. I thought Junction links updated automatically.

"will the link update or do I have to…" – What stops you from trying this scenario on an expendable test folder or so?

You're talking about symbolic links but you're creating a junction. Those are two different things, with various subtle differences. You might also consider using mklink /d to create a symbolic link to a directory, after learning what those differences are.

The link will not update.
You have to delete the link and create a new version in its place.
Do note, if a file is open at C:\MM, you will not be able to move all the data in E:\Data\MM. The same applies if its open at E:\Data\MM, but then its obvious to most people.
